# How do I stop recurring error messages from appearing in messages and auditd.log?

Tags: linux, centos, audit, logrotate, audit-logging

On my CentOS linux machine, in my auditd.conf file, I have set my max_log_file_action=keep_logs.

However, in my /var/log/messages and /var/log/auditd.log, the following message appears multiple times a second which is filling up those log files quickly:

```
Audit daemon rotating log files with keep option
Last known log disappeared (/data/log/audit.log.5)
Next log to use will be /data/log/audit.log.5
```

Why are these messages appearing? Why so frequently? And how do I make them go away?  they are incorrect nuisance messages (i.e., I'm not trying to rotate my auditd log)

Thanks in advance!

-Adeena

Comment: This question isn't programming related. You should ask it on Super User I think.

Comment: Ok! I'll do that. Thx

Comment: Link to the question over there since I or someone will likely close it out over here:  http://superuser.com/questions/874645/how-do-i-stop-recurring-error-messages-from-appearing-in-messages-and-auditd-log

Comment: Good luck! Unfortunately, I don't know the answer.